# Flask template inheritance not working outputting the inheritance commands instead of children

Tags: python, flask

[image]

I was expecting an output along the lines of the above picture however. I have received  as an output.[image]

The base code or the layout code is simply not inheriting the child "home" here and displaying the commands as is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Flask App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css')}}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Ardit's web app</h1>
        <strong><nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav></strong>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        {%block content%}
        {%endblock%}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above code is the code for the layout.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="home">
    <h1>My homepage</h1>
    <p>This is a test website</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This is for the home page or the child. The output screenshots are for this. Even for the layout page it is printing out      {%block content%} {%endblock%} directly.

I have seen the flask example on its documentation page the syntax is the same https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/.

The python scripts I am using is

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import jinja2
#FLask class object from flas

#initializing the class 
app=Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/about/')
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing these lines:

```
{%block content%}
{%endblock%}
```

to this:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Probably these space after-before % causes the issue
In any case, you must try these html files LIVE with your app, not only by opening them with the browser as simple html files, as with the latest way they will always appear with the code, not the content

Comment: Have you tried to open these html files via your app or you just open them as common html files with the browser? If you open them as files html files directly in your browser, they will always appear with th code inside, not the content

Comment: Oh my god that is exactly it I had not been accessing the local server but opening the HTML file.